# How to iterate through a dictionaries values and only pass once if none of the values are empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3, in preferably a one-liner, how do you iterate through a dict's values and only pass once if none of the values are empty? The loop below with the first values example passes twice; however, the goal is to only pass once or not pass at all, so that the code executed after, only executes once.

```
response = dict(request.get_json())
values = SimpleNamespace(**response)

for value in values.__dict__.values():
    if value != "":
        # do things
```

values example that should not pass:

```
{"username","email",""}
```

values example that should pass:

```
{"username","email","password"}
```

Comment: `all(values.__dict__.values())`?

Comment: `all(response.values())` not sure what the namespace is doing there in the first place